# How can I break this statement apart so it's on different lines but performs the same function and output?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

How can I change this

```
new_directions = ['R' if item == 'L' else 'L' if item == 'R' else item
              for item in reversed(directions)]
```

So it looks something like this instead:

```
if item =="L":
    item= "R"

else:
    item=="L"

if item =="R":
    item=="R"

else:
    item == reversed(directions)
```

for item in new_directions:
print(item)

Comment: Your logic seems a bit convoluted. Why not just `['R' if item == 'L' else 'L' for item in reversed(directions)]`? Also -- if you don't want a list comprehension just use a for loop.

Comment: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment. You've got them mixed up in your code.

Comment: @JohnColeman Their code allows for items that aren't `L` or `R`, leaving them unchanged. Your code will change any non-`R` to `L`.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I thought that they were just trying to swap L and R in a convoluted way.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed, they might be, so maybe the second conditional is unnecessary. Or it's just defensive programming.

Comment: Wouldn't I just break the program if direction isn't L or R?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `==` in the statements that should be assigning to `item`.

Replace the conditional operators with `if` and `elif`. You can't do it with multiple `if`, because the second `if` will process the updated `item` from the first `if`, so it will just undo it. You don't need an `else:` statement, since it will just leave `item` alone, which is what happens if neither of the conditions succeed.

You should be looping over `reverse(directions)` with a `for` loop, not assigning it to `item`.

```
new_directions = []

for item in reversed(directions):
    if item == "L":
        item = "R"
    elif item == "R":
        item = "L"
    new_directions.append(item)
```

Comment: If I did this would it make a difference? for item in reversed(directions):
    if item == 'L':
        new_directions.append('R')
    elif item == 'R':
        new_directions.append('L')
    else:
        new_directions.append(item)


for item in new_directions:
    print(item)

Comment: That would work as well. It's just more verbose and not as DRY.

Comment: Your way of explaining is very simple to understand. I was wondering if I could show you an unrelated piece of code to this problem and you explain how the process takes place?

Comment: Post a new question and give me the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74738027/20611666