# How do these counters start at the same thing but count for different things and end up having different results?

Tags: python

```
import random
while True:
    fwd= random.randint(2,20)
    bkwd= random.randint(2,fwd-1)
    total=random.randint(10,85)
    f= 0
    b = 0
    t= 0
    steps_taken= 0

    if bkwd > fwd:
        break

#I don't understand how below this part works
    while total > 0:
        f = 0

        while fwd > f:
            if total > 0:
                print("F", end="")
                f=f+1
                t=t+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1
            else:
               f = fwd
               t = t
               total = total
               steps_taken= steps_taken
#Up until f=fwd

        b = 0

        while bkwd > b:
            if total > 0:
                print("B", end="")
                t=t-1
                b=b+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1
            else:
               b = bkwd
               t = t
               total = total
               steps_taken = steps_taken
           
    if f > total or b > total:
        break

print(" ",t, "steps from the start")
print("Forward:", f, "Backward:", b, "Total:", steps_taken )
```

These are the instructions:

> A person walks a random amount of steps forward, and then a different
> random number of steps backwards.
>
> The random steps are anywhere between 2 and 20 The number of steps
> forward is always greater than the number of steps backwards That
> motion of forward / backward random steps repeats itself again and
> again The motion is consistent (the number of forward steps stays the
> same throughout the motion, and the number of backwards steps stays
> the same throughout the motion) After making a specific amount of
> total steps the person is told to stop and will be a certain amount of
> steps forward from where they started.
>
> The total number of steps is generated randomly and will be between 10
> and 85 You are writing a program to simulate the motion taken by the
> person.
>
> Display that motion and the number of steps he ends away from where he
> started.
>
> For Example:
>
> If the program generated the forward steps to be 4, and the backward
> steps to be 2, and the total number of steps to be 13, your program
> would display:
>
> ```
> FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5 Steps from the start
> ```
>
> If the program generated the forward steps to be 5, and the backward steps to be 3, and the total steps to be 16, your program would display
>
> ```
> FFFFFBBBFFFFFBBB = 4 Steps from the start
> ```

Comment: Like how do the counters start all the same but end up doing different things with different results? And why does else: f = fwd?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  The counters do different things because there's a bunch of code that sets them to different values in what looks to me like an unnecessarily convoluted way.  Was this code part of the assignment?  Did you write it or did somebody else write it for you?  What's your goal here?

Comment: My classmate showed me this and I'm trying to understand it. But if everything starts at 0 and all you do is add or subtract 1, how do they end up with different results???

Comment: That's not all that happens -- if you read the code carefully you'll see that the different variables get set to different values in different ways under different circumstances.  I suggest writing your own code instead of trying to figure out your classmate's code, it doesn't seem like a great example to work from because it's making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Another way to understand how code works is to write down the variables on paper. Then step through the code, following the instructions and updating the variables on the paper.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @koko We're also doing the same thing, assembling letters into words, words into sentences. But we end up with different paragraph yes?